# How to deserialize XML document with inner tags and inner elements?

Tags: c#, xml, object, deserialization

This is my XML file.

```
<getMetadata>
 <Project Name="Doors_Demo">
  <Module FullPath="/Doors_Demo/Test_Module2">
   <Attributes>
    <Attribute name="TableType" type="TableType" /> 
    <Attribute name="TableTopBorder" type="TableEdgeType" /> 
   </Attributes>
  </Module>
 </Project>
</getMetadata>
```

I want to deserialize the above XML

Below is my code:

```
[XmlRoot("getMetadata")]
public class RootClass
{
    public Project element_Project;

    [XmlElement("Project")]
    public Project Project
    {
        get { return element_Project; }
        set { element_Project = value; }
    }
}

public class Project
{
    public string name;

    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Id
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RootClass obj = new RootClass();

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RootClass));
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"E:\getMetadata(4).xml", FileMode.Open))
    {
        RootClass myxml = (RootClass)serializer.Deserialize(stream);

        Console.WriteLine(myxml.Project.name);
    }
}
```

I want to deserialize my XML into a list, I am not able to access all inner elements and attributes inside the root element.

I want details of module element and its inner elements and tags into list which can be accessed.

Comment: 1 puke-emoji for a document with elements called 'Attribute'...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little trick to generate classes from your XML automatically.

First, create a new empty class, name it for example `TempXml`.

Copy your XML to the clipboard and open the new empty class you just created.

Go to Visual Studio *Edit* menu then *Paste Special* and *Paste XML as Classes*:

[image: Paste XML as Classes]

This will generate the following code:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class getMetadata
{

    private getMetadataProject projectField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public getMetadataProject Project
    {
        get
        {
            return this.projectField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.projectField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class getMetadataProject
{

    private getMetadataProjectModule moduleField;

    private string nameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public getMetadataProjectModule Module
    {
        get
        {
            return this.moduleField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.moduleField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class getMetadataProjectModule
{

    private getMetadataProjectModuleAttribute[] attributesField;

    private string fullPathField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Attribute", IsNullable = false)]
    public getMetadataProjectModuleAttribute[] Attributes
    {
        get
        {
            return this.attributesField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.attributesField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string FullPath
    {
        get
        {
            return this.fullPathField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.fullPathField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class getMetadataProjectModuleAttribute
{

    private string nameField;

    private string typeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string type
    {
        get
        {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.typeField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Which should work fine with the `XmlSerializer` class.

You can clean up a little bit the generated output by removing the empty remarks, changing the name of the classes to use camel case (in this case you need to specify the real element name in the attribute as you were doing in your question) or move the classes to different files.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i am only able to fetch project name,i want to fetch module name as well as attributes from the xml,how should i do that ?